# Blazor login page jwt bearer token and authorizing

Tags: jwt, blazor, authorization, blazor-webassembly, bearer-token

```
 @page "/login"
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Text.Json
@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h3>Login</h3>

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage))
{
  <div class="alert alert-danger">@errorMessage</div>
}

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" @bind="email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" @bind="password" />
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Login">Login</button>

@code {
  private string email;
  private string password;
  private string errorMessage;

  private async Task Login()
  {
      try
      {
          var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();

          // Create a JSON object to send to the API
          var loginData = new
          {
              Email = email,
              Password = password
          };

          // Serialize the object to JSON
          var jsonContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(loginData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

          // Send a POST request to your authentication API to get a JWT token
          var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://your-auth-api.com/login", loginData);

          // Check if the request was successful
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              // Deserialize the response to get the JWT token
              var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

              // Store the token securely (e.g., in local storage or a secure cookie)
              // For demonstration, we'll just set it in a session variable
              await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "jwtToken", token);

              // Redirect to the secured page
              NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/secure");
          }
          else
          {
              errorMessage = "Invalid email or password.";
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          errorMessage = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message;
      }
  }
}
```

i am trying to send the login info the api and get a token to use in every page to send to api again, but i am new at blazor so how do i  get to token with jwt bearer and send it to other pages,
and also if anyone check my code snd give me feedback if its true or not ill be so happy. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to get started is in this repo. This was my first introduction and it got me started really quick. https://github.com/cornflourblue/blazor-webassembly-jwt-authentication-example

The documentation and demo are in this page. https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/08/13/blazor-webassembly-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Check this class **"AuthenticationService.cs"** from the repo.

```
using BlazorApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp.Services
{
    public interface IAuthenticationService
    {
        User User { get; }
        Task Initialize();
        Task Login(string username, string password);
        Task Logout();
    }

    public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private IHttpService _httpService;
        private NavigationManager _navigationManager;
        private ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

        public User User { get; private set; }

        public AuthenticationService(
            IHttpService httpService,
            NavigationManager navigationManager,
            ILocalStorageService localStorageService
        ) {
            _httpService = httpService;
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _localStorageService = localStorageService;
        }

        public async Task Initialize()
        {
            User = await _localStorageService.GetItem<User>("user");
        }

        public async Task Login(string username, string password)
        {
            User = await _httpService.Post<User>("/users/authenticate", new { username, password });
            await _localStorageService.SetItem("user", User);
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            User = null;
            await _localStorageService.RemoveItem("user");
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, once you are logged in, you can call your backend this way.

```
namespace BlazorApp.Services
{
    public interface IHttpService
    {
        Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
        Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value);
    }

    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        private NavigationManager _navigationManager;
        private ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;

        public HttpService(
            HttpClient httpClient,
            NavigationManager navigationManager,
            ILocalStorageService localStorageService,
            IConfiguration configuration
        ) {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _localStorageService = localStorageService;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task<T> Get<T>(string uri)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            return await sendRequest<T>(request);
        }

        public async Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return await sendRequest<T>(request);
        }

        // helper methods

        private async Task<T> sendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // add jwt auth header if user is logged in and request is to the api url
            var user = await _localStorageService.GetItem<User>("user");
            var isApiUrl = !request.RequestUri.IsAbsoluteUri;
            if (user != null && isApiUrl)
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", user.Token);

            using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            // auto logout on 401 response
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("logout");
                return default;
            }

            // throw exception on error response
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var error = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                throw new Exception(error["message"]);
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

All the best, and keep coding.